# The organization of a relational database of keyword

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

Need to organize a relational database to store and search for the next.
There messages with keywords:

```
message1 (key word1, kw2, kw3)
message2 (kw2, kw3, kw4)
...
```

Next, you need on a set of keywords to select those messages where most matches keywords found.

For example for: kw2, kw4:

```
message2, count: 2
message1, count: 1
```

How do you think best to organize such a structure? What is the best and quickest way to search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An intersection table can handle these relationships.
An example is below. (Sequences, additional keys etc. omitted)
The message_text is included just for the example--including the fulltext could be a liability if the message data is subject to change.

```
CREATE TABLE MESSAGES
(MESSAGE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,MESSAGE_TEXT VARCHAR2(4000));

CREATE TABLE KEYWORDS
(KEYWORD_ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,KEYWORD VARCHAR2(100));

CREATE TABLE MESSAGES_KEYWORDS
(MESSAGE_ID NOT NULL REFERENCES MESSAGES
,KEYWORD_ID NOT NULL REFERENCES KEYWORDS);

INSERT INTO MESSAGES
VALUES
(1,'IN A HOLE IN THE GROUND THERE LIVED A HOBBIT.');

INSERT INTO MESSAGES
VALUES
(2,'IT WAS A HOBBIT-HOLE, AND THAT MEANS COMFORT');

INSERT INTO KEYWORDS VALUES (1,'HOBBIT');
INSERT INTO KEYWORDS VALUES (2,'GROUND');
INSERT INTO KEYWORDS VALUES (3,'COMFORT');

INSERT INTO MESSAGES_KEYWORDS VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO MESSAGES_KEYWORDS VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO MESSAGES_KEYWORDS VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO MESSAGES_KEYWORDS VALUES (2,3);
```

Querying the relationships joins the three tables:

```
SELECT 
MESSAGES.MESSAGE_TEXT
,KEYWORDS.KEYWORD
FROM MESSAGES
INNER JOIN MESSAGES_KEYWORDS
USING (MESSAGE_ID)
INNER JOIN KEYWORDS
USING (KEYWORD_ID)
WHERE KEYWORDS.KEYWORD = 'HOBBIT';

SELECT 
MESSAGES.MESSAGE_ID
,COUNT('X') COUNT_KEYWORDS
FROM MESSAGES
INNER JOIN MESSAGES_KEYWORDS
ON (MESSAGES.MESSAGE_ID = MESSAGES_KEYWORDS.MESSAGE_ID)
AND MESSAGES.MESSAGE_ID = 1
INNER JOIN KEYWORDS
USING (KEYWORD_ID)
GROUP BY MESSAGES.MESSAGE_ID;
```